# How does a native speaker express there is no problem except an error

Tags: phrase-request

Someone provided me a business document and asked me to check it and I have found an error.

If i want to point out the error, how would a native speaker express "there is no problem except this one I found"?

Comment: It's OK to say There is no problem except it or this one.

Comment: I am not a native speaker but i would say "there is no problem but ..." in this context "but" means "other than"/"except"

Answer (score 2):

I would say

"**Everything looks good except for** a typo in the first sentence of the third paragraph."

That is a little informal, and if you wanted to be more formal you could say

"**The document is correct except for** the typo on line 63."

Answer (score 0):

You could say *"There is no error except in this para"* or *"There is a little error here"* or *"You should have a little change here"*.

Comment: Expect is not correct and I wouldn't abbreviate paragraph as para.

Comment: Sorry, a small typing error ! and yes, if you are using english(uk) dialect, you won't do that! But, i don't think that's a problem in us english dialect.

Comment: I am American. Abbreviating paragraph is not incorrect, but I wouldn't do it unless I was working with documents that had a lot of references to paragraphs and subsections, like specifications or legal documents. For general purpose correspondence I would write it out.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I won't either. But, here he has a business document.