# How to describe the situation where there's a small problem but everything else is fine?

Tags: phrase-request

I can think of:

> The program works fine but there is one problem.

And that statement is plain wrong because if the program is fine then there shouldn't be a problem. But if there is a problem that means that the program doesn't work fine.

But I want to say that majority of the program works fine and some part doesn't.

***How do I say that in a neat way?***

Comment: "Aside from one minor issue the program works fine."  
"Apart from one small bug the program works fine."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a native speaker express there is no problem except an error](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47887/how-does-a-native-speaker-express-there-is-no-problem-except-an-error)

Comment: There's a glitch, a blip,  hiccup, a small wrinkle that needs ironing out ...

Answer (score 3):

Others may disagree, but I think "glitch" might fit.

- "one minor glitch". and if you're sure it's fixable, say "fixable glitch" .
- If you think the program could be put into use despite the problem, say "it's not a show-stopper".
- If the problem can be documented around, it's "not a bug, it's a feature" (that's an IT joke; not one you would tell a customer.) 
  But seriously, if users could be trained to work around it, "it's a training issue".
- If it's a feature that was in the spec, but can't be delivered in this release, say that it "won't be in the initial rollout", but that it (i.e. getting it working) is "on the wish list for Phase Two".

Comment: "documented around"... interesting turn of phrase.

Comment: I'm a documenter by trade.  And a former programmer.  If a program were perfectly reliable as well as intuitive, it would need NO documentation.  Therefore, the main point of user documentation is to explain functions that do NOT perform as expected. For example, to warn users NOT to enter certain input  (e.g., input that screws something up—maybe not now, but down the pipeline) that the program should trap, but doesn't.

Comment: Can I say - "The program works fine except one glitch"?

Comment: ". . . except _for_ one glitch." Or . . but there's one glitch." "Otherwise, you are saying the program works but the glitch doesn't. This is a tautology; a glitch **couldn't** work, because then it wouldn't be a glitch.